# Need help to display data into text area from selected link

Tags: php

Hi I need to display the blog string from the selected links ... my code is as follows ... Now all i need is display the data by clicking the particular link ... for example if i selected the first title named test1 i want to display only that blog in textarea ... please help thank you.

```
<?php 
    $order = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY strTitle";
    $result = mysql_query($order);  
    while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {   
?> 
    <a href=""><?php echo("<tr><td>$data[1]</td>"); ?> </a> 
    <br/>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should forget about those queries and start to read about PDO

Comment: the question is slightly confusing, I am not actually sure what exactly you want to do.
are those data you wanted to display in the DB as well? or are you only store link in DB and the data is somewhere on the internet?

Comment: Create a script that can write a database entry (identified by a key via the script parameters) and then add a link to this script. e.g. `<a href="edit.php?entry=<?=$key ?>">Edit</a>` and in the edit script `select ... from ... where ...='.$key.'"`. Check proper handling of `$key` to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Jacky data is in the Db only ... I just want to display the data by their unique id ... I am confused how to pass those links inside loop ... or is there any other way ???

Answer (score 0):

On each link pass unique id or name.
   And Then Request this id on top of the page.And after it run your sql query as

`$order = "SELECT * FROM blog  where first_titled = $rquest_id ORDER BY strTitle";`

and the fetch result

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. Meaning that it only works on the server and it is not visible to the user.

If you want the link to display the blog data one the same page, I think it could be done with javascript and css.You could insert the whole blogs data in the page but make them all hidden and when you click the link this triggers an event to display the corresponding data and hide any visible one.

If you want to do it in PHP then you have to create links that open another page where you pass arguments to this page for the php code to catch and make the a query based on what you passed.
the link could be :

```
page.php?id=11
```

and in the page you make a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=11
```

Hope this helps.